# match words in all rows in same column

Tags: oracle, plsql

There is a column in table 'mytable' named 'Description'.

```
+----+-------------------------------+
| ID | Description                   |
+----+-------------------------------+
| 1  | My NAME is Sajid KHAN         |
| 2  | My Name is Ahmed Khan         |
| 3  | MY friend name is Salman Khan |
+----+-------------------------------+
```

I need to write an Oracle SQL query/procedure/function to list the distinct words in the column.

The output should be:

```
+------------------+-------+
| Word             | Count |
+------------------+-------+
| MY               |     3 |
| NAME             |     3 |
| IS               |     3 |
| SAJID            |     1 |
| KHAN             |     3 |
| AHMED            |     1 |
| FRIEND           |     1 |
| SALMAN           |     1 |
+------------------+-------+
```

Word matching should be case-insensitive.

I am using Oracle 12.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's suppose we would somehow manage to split every description in words.
So, instead of single row with Id = 1 and Description = 'My NAME is Sajid KHAN' we'd have 5 rows like this

```
ID  | Description
--- | ------------
 1  | My 
 1  | NAME 
 1  | is 
 1  | Sajid 
 1  | KHAN
```

in this form it'd be trivial, something like

```
select Description, count(*) from data_in_new_form group by Description
```

So, let's do this using recursive query.

```sql
create table mytable
as
select 1 as ID, 'My NAME is Sajid KHAN' as Description from dual
union all 
select 2, 'My Name is Ahmed Khan' from dual
union all
select 3, 'MY friend name is Salman Khan' from dual
union all
select 4, 'test, punctuation! it is' from dual
;


with
rec (id, str, depth, element_value) as
(
    -- Anchor member.
    select id, upper(Description) as str, 1 as depth, REGEXP_SUBSTR( upper(Description), '(.*?)( |$)', 1, 1, NULL, 1 ) AS element_value
     from mytable
    UNION ALL
    -- Recursive member.
    select id, str, depth + 1, REGEXP_SUBSTR( str ,'(.*?)( |$)', 1, depth+1, NULL, 1 ) AS element_value
     from rec
    where depth < regexp_count(str, ' ')+1
)
, data as (
select * from rec
--order by id, depth
)
select element_value, count(*) from data
group by element_value
order by element_value
;
```

Please notice this version doesn't do anything about punctuation assuming words are separated with spaces.

**UPDATE** alternative way using hierarchic query

```
with rec as
(
    SELECT id, LEVEL AS depth,
    REGEXP_SUBSTR( upper(description) ,'(.*?)( |$)', 1, LEVEL, NULL, 1 ) AS element_value
    FROM   mytable
    CONNECT BY LEVEL <= regexp_count(description, ' ')+1
    and prior id = id
    and prior SYS_GUID() is not null
)
, data as (
select * from rec
--order by id, depth
)
select element_value, count(*) from data
group by element_value
order by 2 desc
;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick response. i try this query and its works fine. .

Comment: i have oracle 10g,11g and 12c.
this query only works in 12c not in 10g and 11g is their any equivalent query for 10g,11g??????????

Comment: it's very strange: just tested the recursive query on a 11g DB and it works fine. Try using the hierarchic version.

Comment: its not working as it is.
i am using it on Oracle 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0
 but if i change it to this than its works.

select element_value,count(*) from 
(
    SELECT id, LEVEL AS depth,
    REGEXP_SUBSTR( upper(description) ,'(.*?)( |$)', 1, LEVEL, NULL, 1 ) AS element_value
    FROM   mytable
    CONNECT BY LEVEL <= regexp_count(description, ' ')+1
    and prior id = id
    and prior SYS_GUID() is not null
)
group by element_value

Answer (score 0):

This query will work. The ordering of the words may be different. However, frequent words come at the beginning as you have listed.

```
  SELECT word,
      COUNT(*)
       FROM
      (SELECT TRIM (REGEXP_SUBSTR (Description, '[^ ]+', 1, ROWNUM) ) AS Word
       FROM
        (SELECT LISTAGG(UPPER(Description),' ') within GROUP(
          ORDER BY ROWNUM ) AS Description
        FROM mytable
        )
        CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT ( Description, '[^ ]+')
      )
    GROUP BY WORD
    ORDER BY 2 DESC;
```

Comment: that `LISTAGG` can raise an `ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too long` exception.

Comment: Thanks man this also works for me as my column is varchar(100) so my string is not too long.

Comment: but how many of such columns are You going to concatenate? 40 such rows could be already too long.